# Kafka custom message converter not invoked

Tags: listener, message, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, converters

I have created a Kafka listener with my container factory with the following code. I am specifying a custom message converter (HeaderMessageConverter in below code) while setting up the container factory. When my listener is created, I can even verify that the custom message converter is assigned to it.

```
        String prefix = topic + propConstant;
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(getConsumerFactory(topic));
        factory.setConcurrency(config.getInt(prefix  + "concurrency"));
        factory.setBatchListener(config.getBoolean(prefix + "batch.listener"));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new HeaderMessageConverter());
        return factory;


public class HeaderMessageConverter implements BatchMessageConverter {
    
    /**
     * Convert a list of {@link ConsumerRecord} to a {@link Message}.
     *
     * @param records        the records.
     * @param acknowledgment the acknowledgment.
     * @param payloadType    the required payload type.
     * @return the message.
     */
    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Type payloadType) {

        Map<String, Object> rawHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        List<Object> payloads = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Map<String , Object>> customHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> offsets = new ArrayList<>();
        rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, keys);
        rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC, topics);
        rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, partitions);
        rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, offsets);
        rawHeaders.put("CUSTOM_HEADERS", customHeaders);

        if (acknowledgment != null) {
            rawHeaders.put(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, acknowledgment);
        }
        
        for (ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record : records) {
            payloads.add(extractAndConvertValue(record, payloadType));
            keys.add(record.key());
            Map<String, Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Header header : record.headers()) {
                headerMap.put(header.key(), new String(header.value()));
            }
            topics.add(record.topic());
            partitions.add(record.partition());
            offsets.add(record.offset());
            customHeaders.add(headerMap);
        }
        MessageHeaders kafkaMessageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(rawHeaders);
        return MessageBuilder.createMessage(payloads, kafkaMessageHeaders);
    }
```

However, once the listener consumes the message, instead of going to the overridden toMessage method of HeaderMessageConverter, it goes to toMessage method of org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.java provided by spring-kafka.

I am using Spring Kafka 1.1.8. Any idea why my custom message converter toMessage is not invoked?

Comment: Spring Kafka 1.1.x has not been supported for several years now; even 1.3.11 will not be supported after this year. The current version is 2.6.4; if you still have a problem with a [supported version](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn), post a complete verifiable simple example that exhibits the behavior you see.

Comment: @GaryRussell I don't have the option to upgrade the spring Kafka version just yet. I have also figured why my custom message converter is not invoked and why it uses MessagingMessageConverter. Is there a way to provide your own version of BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter?

Comment: 1.1.x has a very complex threading model; at the very least you should upgrade to 1.3.11 which is a lot simpler, thanks to KIP-62. To override the adapter you would have to subclass the `MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint` and override `createMessageListenerInstance()`. To use the custom endpoint you would have to subclass the `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and override `processKafkaListener()` (this is based on the current state of the code; I have not looked at the ancient versions to see if this was possible then).